# How to rotate a cgpath before drawing it?

Tags: core-animation, core-graphics, rotation, quartz-graphics, cgpath

I can draw a path...and i am somewhat sure that i need to use affine transform.

what i don't get is how to rotate the path and keep the same center.

I apologize for the lack of code here...but all I have is a failed call to CGContextRotateCTM that seemed to halt all drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate around the center:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM (ctx, center.x, center.y);
CGContextRotateCTM (ctx, angleInRadians);
CGContextTranslateCTM (ctx, -center.x, -center.y);
CGContextAddPath (ctx, path);
```

I might have the translate signs backward (i.e. negative translation before rotate instead of after), although I believe the CTM methods pre-concat, so the mathematical representation of those calls is

```
CTMnew = -T * R * T * CTMcurrent
```

Comment: well I'll be. I had given up on the question. I'll try this out later.